# Simple transpile & node_module imports

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, jsx, babeljs

I have some source code organised like this:

```
src/
  App/
    App.index.jsx
    index.css
  index.html
  index.jsx
```

The source code uses some npm packages (let's say, React and Lodash).

Currently, I've got a simple babel setup to transpile my jsx source code to this:

```
dist/
  App/
    App.index.js
    index.css
  index.html
  index.js
```

That's exactly what I want—except imports of node_modules don't work (they're untouched, and thus obviously fail):

```js
import { jsx as _jsx } from "react/jsx-runtime.js"; // broken
import { render } from 'react-dom'; // broken
import App from './App/App.index.jsx'; // works
render( /*#__PURE__*/_jsx(App, {}), document.getElementById('root'));
//# sourceMappingURL=index.js.map
```

The Babel docs indicate that that is just the default behaviour, but can be overridden (yet does not specifically say how). I've tried every combination of "include", "exclude", "ignore", and "override" imaginable, but to no difference. And everything I find related to Babel for this that appears remotely related is outdated.

Throwing Webpack into the mix seems overkill, but I could live with it if truly necessary. However, my non-bundled source-code seems contrary to what Webpack is designed to do. I can easily get Webpack to compile a vendors.js file, but not the above output.

I'm looking for a simple solution that merely enables imports of npm packages to work. The two options that come to mind are:

1. Bundle all imported packages into a vendor file:

```
dist/
  App/
    App.index.js
    index.css
  index.js
  index.html
  vendor.js
```

2. Copy the relevant imported packages into the output directory in some fashion, and update the transpiled source code's imports:

```
dist/
  vendor/
    lodash/
      …
    react/
      …
  App/
    App.index.js
    index.css
  index.js
  index.html
```

```js
import { jsx as _jsx } from "./vendor/react/jsx-runtime.js";
import { render } from './vendor/react-dom.js';
import App from './App/App.index.jsx';
render( /*#__PURE__*/_jsx(App, {}), document.getElementById('root'));
//# sourceMappingURL=index.js.map
```

I feel like this is an extremely simple issue for which I can find only hugely over-engineered solutions.

My current (babel part of) package.json:

```json
{
  "babel": {
    "include": [ // this does nothing
      "./node_modules/**/*",
      "./src/**/*"
    ],
    "plugins": [
      [
        "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx",
        { "runtime": "automatic" }
      ]
    ]
  },
}
```

Comment: I just stumbled across [babel-plugin-bare-import-rewrite](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-bare-import-rewrite) sort of does option 2: it re-writes the paths to point to their location in node_modules (ex `"react/jsx-runtime.js"` → `"../node_modules/react/jsx-runtime.js"`). I think not ideal, but workable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Snowpack](https://www.snowpack.dev) ([npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/snowpack)) is exactly what I was looking for (aside from css modules being broken until the approved PR is merged).